# How to determine the iterator type for container?

Tags: c++, type-traits

What do I have to write for YYY, ZZZ in order to set `iterator_type` to the iterator type associated with `T` ? It should work in Visual Studio C++ 2010, if possible (but general standard solution is ok as well).

```
template<class T>
struct iterator_for {
    typedef YYY<T>::ZZZ type;
}
```

Hence I want:

```
iterator_for<double[3]>::type is double *
iterator_for<std::string>::type is std::string::iterator
iterator_for<char[12]>::type is char *
```

etc.

I have a templated wrapper class `Wrapper<T>` storing something iterable (i.e. a container or string or an array) and I want to define a function returning an iterator pointing into the wrapped object. For that purpose, I need to be able to speak about the iterator type corresponding to `T`. For an array, the corresponding iterator would be a pointer, and for a string that is whatever string defines to be its iterator type.

Comment: i guess you need to use SFINAE to check if `iterator_type` is declared inside `T` and if that failed  - just `typedef T* type`

Comment: Isn't that predefined anywhere?

Comment: What is the bigger problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You have to state your question more precisely. What you have now is inconsistent and, honestly, makes little sense. If iterator type for `double *` is `double *`, then why is it that for `string` it is suddenly `string::iterator` and not `string *`? What concept are you trying to implement? What is that iterator type is supposed to iterate over?

Comment: Bigger problem: I have a templated wrapper class `Wrapper<T>` storing something iterable (i.e. a container or string or an array) and I want to define a function returning an iterator pointing into the wrapped object. For that purpose, I need to be able to speak about the iterator type corresponding to `T`. For an array, the corresponding iterator would be a pointer, and for a string that is whatever string defines to be its iterator type.

Comment: @JohnB: Ah, I think the misunderstanding was because you forgot that _arrays are not pointers_.  I altered the code in the question to actually map from arrays to pointers, rather than pointers to pointers, so its consistent and makes sense now.  I'm fairly certain this is the concept you want, but please confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to separate containers from pointers, you can try this

```
template<class T>
struct iterator_for 
{
    typedef typename T::iterator  type;
};

template<class T>
struct iterator_for<T*>
{
    typedef T*  type;
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct iterator_for<T (&)[N]>
{
    typedef T*  type;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

My solution is:

```
typedef decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T&>())) type;
```

The iterator type is the type returned by `std::begin` when called on an instance of `T`. `std::declval<T&>` is declared to return a `T&`, on which we can call `std::begin`.

This differs from JohnB's answer in that we pass a reference to the container type to `std::begin`. This is needed because:

- `std::declval<T>()` returns an rvalue reference (`T&&`).
- `std::begin` takes its argument by non-const reference.
- A non-const reference can't bind to a temporary.

`std::declval<T&>` however returns an lvalue refernce because of reference collapsing.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, one possibility probably is (in C++11, but does not work in VS 2010):

```
typedef typename std::remove_reference<
                    decltype ( 
                        begin ( std::declval<T> () )
                    )
                 >::type
        type;
```

Comment: This may introduce a side effect - std::declval<T>() is an rvalue so it will bind to begin(const T&) ... it will create a const iterator type.

Answer (score 1):

The Boost library already has this:

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> void print_list(const T& container) {
    typedef typename boost::range_iterator<const T>::type iter;
    for (iter i = boost::begin(container); i != boost::end(container); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ";";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    double array[] = {1.0,2.0,3.0};
    std::string str = "Hello";
    std::vector<int> vec(3, 10);
    print_list(array);  // prints 1;2;3;
    print_list(str);    // prints H;e;l;l;o;
    print_list(vec);    // prints 10;10;10;
}
```